# If i display loading image(gif) in "head" tag will it be bad practice?

Tags: html, image, loading, gif

If i display loading image(gif) in "head" tag will it be bad practice? if it is, how bad?
Actually when i add image in the body tag it appears later. But i want it to show as fast as the user enter the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a good practice (if you are using a script in the "head" which load the gif) so you can put your image wherever in your html code (in the body tag). It will be loaded as soon as the script is read by the parser (that's why putting it in the head doesn't surprise me).

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/